# Is there a way to dynamically insert html form into a div in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS data collection "wizard" app.
In this wizard there will be around 100 steps.
I'm looking for a way to dynamically insert/merge different html forms within each wizard step markup.
The structure of the wizard itself looks tike this:

```
<wizard on-finish="finished()"> 
    <wz-step title="Step 1">
        <h1>This is Step 1</h1>
        <p>Need to dynamically insert a form here</p>
        <input type="submit" wz-next value="Proceed to Next Step" />
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step title="Step 2">
        <h1>This is Step 2</h1>
        <p>Need to dynamically insert a form here</p>
        <input type="submit" wz-next value="Proceed to Next Step" />
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step title="Step 3">
    <h1>This is Step 3</h1>
        <p>Even more steps!!</p>
        <input type="submit" wz-next value="Finish now" />
    </wz-step>
</wizard>
```

I would much rather have a 100 separate little html files (one for each step), then put all of markup in a single wizard.html file.
Ideally, I would like to have, let's say, a file named step1.html, who's contents would be dynamically loaded into the wizard.html in place of

```
<p>Need to dynamically insert a form here</p>
```

Is there an AngularJS way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ngInclude`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

`<p ng-include="step1.html">Need to dynamically insert a form here</p>`

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways one is by using ng-include as stated above, make sure your template is in srtipt tags ie

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemp">
//your html

</script>
```

and in ng include

```
<div ng-include="myTemp"></div>
```

or if you have html hardcoded in a js variable and want to append to a div whose id you knwow then the following will do:

```
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```

and your variable is

```
var myHtml="<div> hello dude <span ng-repeat="obj in objects"></span><div>"
```

then in this case you need to compile this html so that angular directives in this case ng-repeat can function.

```
var compiled=$compile(myHtml)($scope);
angular.element("#myDiv").append(compiled);
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out Angular-UI's ui-router.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

It expands upon routes adding support for a state-machine and nested routes which may get you where you are going.

Comment: the question is not about changing routes, its about changing templates